# How does Lipschitz Continuity of the gradient implies that the Hessian-Matrix minus Lipschitz-Constant is negativ semidefinit?

Tags: vector-analysis, lipschitz-functions, positive-semidefinite, gradient-descent, hessian-matrix

I was reading following lecture notes [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F13/scribes/lec6.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-F13/scribes/lec6.pdf) In the proof the author says that if the gradient $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz-continuous than $H_f(x)-LI$ is negative semidefinite, where L is the Lipschitz-constant and $I$ is the unit matrix. This means
$$ ||\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)|| \leq L ||x-y|| \implies \forall x: x^T(H_f(x)-LI)x \leq 0$$
I don't know why this is true. Can someone show a proof of it? Thanks

Comment: Apply [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158328/lipschitz-continuous-and-jacobian-matrix) to the gradient.

Comment: Hey @Miguel yes the second one was very helpful. Thanks for your help!