# Why is the Log-Sum-Exp function 1-smooth

Tags: smooth-functions

This may be a trivial question. I tried to find the proof for the smoothness of the log-sum-exp function $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$, defined as
$$f(x) = \log \sum_i \mathrm{exp}(x_i).$$

I have seen on multiple papers stating that the log-sum-exp function is 1-smooth with respect to the $\ell_2$$ norm, but had no luck proving it myself nor finding the reference online. Can someone point me to a reference or just give me a proof?

A function is $L$-smooth with respect to the $\ell_2$ norm if
$$\Vert \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\Vert_2 \leq L \Vert x - y \Vert_2. $$

Thanks!

Comment: I found a proof in Beck's Book: First-Order Methods in Optimization, Example 5.15. Just for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start we can calculate the first and second partial derivatives of $f$
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} f(x) &= \frac{\exp(x_j)}{\sum_i \exp(x_i)} \\
    \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x_j} f(x) &= \frac{\exp(x_j)\left( \sum_{i} \exp(x_i)\right ) - \exp(x_j)^2}{\left ( \sum_{i} \exp(x_i) \right )^2} \\
    &= \frac{\exp(x_j)\left( \sum_{i\neq j} \exp(x_i)\right)}{\left(\sum_i\exp(x_i)\right)^2} \\
    \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j \partial x_k} &= -\frac{\exp(x_j)\exp(x_k)}{\left (\sum_{i} \exp(x_i) \right )^2} & (j \neq k)
\end{align}
These are all done using standard rules (chain rule, quotient rule, derivative of log and exp).

Next we are going to try and apply the [Gershgorin Circle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) to the Hessian of $f$. To do so we need to define Gershgorin discs. For each row $j$, the disk $D_j$ is defined by its center
$$c_j \triangleq Hf(x)_{jj} =\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2x_j} f(x)$$ and the and its radius
$$
   r_j = \sum_{k\neq j} |Hf(x)_{jk}| = \sum_{k \neq j} \left | \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j \partial x_k} f(x)\right |
$$
The Gershgorin Circle Theorem asserts that the eigenvalues of $Hf(x)$ are contained in the union of the disks $D_j$. We also know by the [Spectral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) and the fact that the Hessian is symmetric that the eigenvalues of $Hf(x)$ are real. What we want to show is that $c_j + r_j \leq 1$ and $c_j - r_j \geq 1$ for every $j$ since this will imply that all the eigenvalues of $Hf(x)$ are contained in $[-1,1]$, for any $x$.

To start note that from the calculations above we have
\begin{align}
    c_j - r_j &= \frac{\exp(x_j)\left( \sum_{i\neq j} \exp(x_i)\right)}{\left(\sum_i\exp(x_i)\right)^2} - \sum_{k\neq j} \frac{\exp(x_j)\exp(x_k)}{\left (\sum_{i} \exp(x_i) \right )^2} = 0 \geq -1 \\
    c_j + r_j &= \frac{\exp(x_j)\left( \sum_{i\neq j} \exp(x_i)\right)}{\left(\sum_i\exp(x_i)\right)^2} + \sum_{k\neq j} \frac{\exp(x_j)\exp(x_k)}{\left (\sum_{i} \exp(x_i) \right )^2} \\
    &= \frac{2\exp(x_j)\left( \sum_{i\neq j} \exp(x_i)\right)}{\left(\sum_i\exp(x_i)\right)^2}  \leq \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
To see the last inequality, let $\alpha = \exp(x_j)$ and $\beta = \sum_{k \neq j} \exp(x_k)$. Then it is equivalent to show
$$
   \frac{2\alpha\beta}{(\alpha + \beta)^2} \leq \frac{1}{2} \iff 4\alpha \beta \leq (\alpha + \beta)^2 \iff 0 \leq \alpha^2 + 2\alpha\beta + \beta^2 - 4\alpha \beta = (\alpha - \beta)^2
$$
and the last expression clearly holds. (also note that $\alpha,\beta > 0$ so there are no dividing by zero issues). Overall this shows that the real parts of $D_j$ is contained in the interval $[0,1/2]$. This turns out to be stronger than you're asking actually.

Now we need one more analysis fact. For any function $F:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, if the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) of the Jacobian of $F$ satisfies
$$\max_x ||JF(x)||_{\text{op}} \leq L$$
then $F$ is $L$-[Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity). That is to say, under this condition $||F(x) - F(y)||_2 \leq L||x-y||_2$ for every $x,y$. ([see here for proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158328/lipschitz-continuous-and-jacobian-matrix))

Note that $\nabla f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ and by definition the Jacobian $J(\nabla f) = Hf$ the hessian of $f$. The argument above shows that $||Hf(x)||_{\text{op}} \leq 1/2$ since all the eigenvalues of $Hf \in [0,1/2]$. In turn we have $\nabla f$ is $(1/2)$-Lipschitz. Therefore we can arrive at the result
$$||\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)|| \leq \frac{1}{2}||x - y||.$$
(Which is actually stronger than what you asked for)

Above we need the eigenvalues to be in $[-1,1]$ to ensure that the $\nabla f$ was 1-Lipschitz, it just happened to be that we could do a little bit better than that.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I still need to take a closer look at the Gershgorin Circle Theorem. But thank you again for such a detailed answer!